# Popularity contest for Fedora and friends?

Tags: debian, fedora

For [Debian](http://popcon.debian.org/) and [Ubuntu](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) there is the populartiiy contest package and result pages (Popcon). Is there something similar for Fedora?

And what about derivatives like RHEL, CentOS, Scientific Linux etc.?

I found just [old](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA%3aSummer_Coding_Ideas_-_Popularity_contest_for_Fedora) [proposals](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA%3aSummer_of_Code_Ideas#Popularity_contest_for_Fedora) and a [blog post of an Open Suse effort](http://stick.gk2.sk/blog/2009/03/popcorn-popularity-contest-for-rpm/) from 2009. What is the current status of such efforts?

Answer (score 2):

[The end of the thread discussing the product](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-May/135501.html) seems to to indicate that it wouldn't be terribly useful to Fedora.  It would require infrastructure changes to fedora mirrors so it's not a simple task to implement.

Comment: Well, with a popcon-like approach the usage data is collected on (and send from) end user machines (via a cron job that queries the package db and the atimes of executables and so on) - for this you don't need mirror infrastructure changes. The discussion in the linked thread is kind of unstructured - but one maintainer is strictly against any package data collection because he can't see how it would be useful (although some use cases are presented).